# Docker - Make docker containers use my public ip

Tags: docker, docker-compose

## Problem

I have a react app running inside a container. I need to request an API(not mine) and it only accepts public IP addresses. Can the container use the public address of my machine?

## Docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:

client:
  container_name: client
  build:
    context: ./client
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - './client:/usr/src/app'
    - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=development
    - NODE_PATH=src
```

Comment: You can run it in network_mode: host and then it will receive an IP on your network just like the host

Comment: Request made from react generally come from the browser rather than the docker container unless you are SSR as such will be routed through your IP if you are requesting and external resource. You are most likely running into a CORS issue, rather than a docker one

Comment: I thought about that but react has something to proxy your requests in development. (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development) @user1095118

Comment: @Mihai I changed to use network_mode but it's using a private IP instead of my public IP

Comment: @TiagoMartins From outside your container should look exactly like your host (network-wise). So if you can connect to that API from your host you should be able to connect from your container as well. Have you checked that?

Comment: @Mihal I thought the problem was the container, but it's react. For osme reason it  is not using a public IP to make the requests. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @TiagoMartins I am not sure that you wan't to use the proxy feature if you are requesting an external API. My understanding of the proxy is used when "the front-end React app is being served from the same host and port as their backend server"

Comment: Would you mind closing this question? I guess if you still have problems with that issue, you should open a new one.

Comment: I totally forgot. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your question: **Can the container use the public address of my machine?**

Yes, it even does so if you do not specify `--net host`. You can check that easily using [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/appropriate/curl) (or any other image that contains `curl`):

First, run this on your host:

```
curl -s ipinfo.io/ip
```

This will show your current public IP address.

Then, run the container:

```
docker run --rm appropriate/curl -s ipinfo.io/ip
```

It should result in the same IP address.

I don't know anything about React, though, so there might be other stuff going on in your case, but basically this should not be a Docker problem.

Comment: I ran that command inside my container and it has the correct public IP. I don't know why but react is using a private IP to host. Thanks for helping to spot the problem.

Comment: No problem. :) I'd suggest you either edit your post to narrow down the problem to something React, or you mark it as solved.