# I can not access by public IP to my Docker Node.js container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, ip

I have a Docker Node.js container listening port 4757 with NET library, using my Public IP.

```
server listening on {"address":"144.xxx.xxx.66","family":"IPv4","port":4757}
```

When I access from my computer I do not have problem,  but If I try to access to my mobile or other device the connection is refused (ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE).

- I have Linux firewall disabled.
- If I do a ping to my Public IP it working correctly.
- I have the port 4757 open in my router ZTE (Yoigo) with LAN Host 192.168.1.128 TCP and UPD

The application worked correctly by docker-composer in other laptop, the problem is in my new laptop. It is my local.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
  image: hegeo_local_django
  depends_on:
    - postgres
  volumes:
    .:/app
  env_file:
    - ./.envs/.local/.django
    - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  command: /start
  networks:
    default:
      ipv4_address: 144.xxx.xxx.3

  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/nodejs/Dockerfile
    image: hegeo_node
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "4757:4757"
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 144.xxx.xxx.66

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: hegeo_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 144.xxx.xxx.4

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: 144.xxx.xxx.0/24
```

I think that I have to use "docker run" but not working neither.
[Docker - Make docker containers use my public ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55779832/docker-make-docker-containers-use-my-public-ip)

EDIT: 
The point is, I used a Network "Driver" because I receive traces from a geolocation device and I need parser this trace with Node.js and send it to Django. If I not set a Network and assign a ipv4_address to Django the connection between Django and Node.js not working.

Comment: remove this `ipv4_address: 144.xxx.xxx.66` in your new laptop

Comment: Thanks, It work but I need set ipv4_address, I updated my post explaining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you have the port open and forwarded from your router to your laptop.
your docker yaml doesn't need to know about the public IP, so you should remove the network settings and go for some thing like:

```
Internet > (public IP) Router (NAT to Local Docker host machine IP) > Docker host laptop (with firewall off, or port open) > docker engine (port is mapped from host to container)  > your Node.js script listening to on the port.
```

Comment: Another information for reference, you can't just assign public IPs unless you actually  have bought them from your ISP, and they routed them properly to your router.

Comment: Thanks, It work but I need this network settings, I updated my post explaining it.

Comment: You can assign IPs, just not public IPs. Try a simple 10.x.x.x range, the port mapping will take care of the incoming traffic, and you can use the private IP you set to communicate with django.